# my notifications only shows up in the morning! [kotlin]

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, notifications, android-notifications

so after I learned a lot about notification channels and how to implement them on my app. I was able to make my app throw a notification to the user's mobile phone. But now, my notification only shows up in the morning. For example, if I set the calendar to throw at a specific time like  `calendar[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY]=8` and `calendar[Calendar.MINUTE] = 38` the notification will show up at 8:38 am not the time I needed which is 8:38 pm !

I have 5 notifications and all of them works only in the morning time "am", not in the nighttime "pm"!

any help would be appreciated (you can use java or kotlin)

**My notification channel**

```
private fun createNotificationChannels(){

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        val channelName = "أذان الفجر"
        val DESCRIPTION_TEXT = "أشعار لأذان الفجر"

        val name = channelName
        val description_text = DESCRIPTION_TEXT
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID_FIRST, name, importance).apply {
            description = description_text
        }

        val channelName1 = "موعد الشروق"
        val DESCRIPTION_TEXT1 = "أشعار لموعد الشروق"
        val name1 = channelName1
        val description_text1 = DESCRIPTION_TEXT1
        val importance1 = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val channel1 = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID_SECOND, name1, importance1).apply {
            description = description_text1
        }

        val channelName2 = "أذان الظهر"
        val DESCRIPTION_TEXT2 = "أشعار لموعد صلاة الظهر"
        val name2 = channelName2
        val description_text2 = DESCRIPTION_TEXT2
        val importance2 = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val channel2 = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID_THIRD, name2, importance2).apply {
            description = description_text2
        }

        val channelName3 = "أذان العصر"
        val DESCRIPTION_TEXT3 = "أشعار لموعد صلاة العصر"
        val name3 = channelName3
        val description_text3 = DESCRIPTION_TEXT3
        val importance3 = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val channel3 = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID_FOUR, name3, importance3).apply {
            description = description_text3
        }
        val channelName4 = "أذان المغرب"
        val DESCRIPTION_TEXT4 = "أشعار لموعد صلاة المغرب"
        val name4 = channelName4
        val description_text4 = DESCRIPTION_TEXT4
        val importance4 = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val channel4 = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID_FIVE, name4, importance4).apply {
            description = description_text4
        }
        val channelName5 = "أذان العشاء"
        val DESCRIPTION_TEXT5 = "أشعار لأذان العشاء"
        val name5 = channelName5
        val description_text5 = DESCRIPTION_TEXT5
        val importance5 = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val channel5 = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID_SIX, name5, importance5).apply {
            description = description_text5
        }
        val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel1)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel2)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel3)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel4)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel5)
    }

}
```

**My broadcast**  // I have 5 of them and they look like this except the title and the id

```
 override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

    val i = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    }
    val pendingIntent : PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,i,0)

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context!!, notifictionChannels().CHANNEL_ID_FOUR)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("صلاة العصر قد حلت")
        .setContentText("بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم, صلاة العصر")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)

    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
        notify(4, builder.build())
    }


}
```

**my notification**

```
     private var asar_status : Boolean = true
            asrSwitch.isChecked = saveData.getBoolean("asarTimesSwitch", true)
        asar_status = saveData.getBoolean("asarTXT", true)
 // asar text
        if (asar_status){
            asrTxt.text = ("" + saveData.getInt("asarTimeHour", 0) + ":"
                    + saveData.getInt("asarTimeMinutes",0) + " PM")
        }else{
            asrTxt.text = " "
        }

 asrSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked){
                editor.putBoolean("asarTimesSwitch",true)
                editor.putBoolean("asarTXT", true)
                editor.apply()
                asrSwitch.isChecked = true
                val  asarTime = getSharedPreferences("saveSettingData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

                calender = Calendar.getInstance()

                
                    calender[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = asarTime.getInt("asarTimeHour", 0)
                    calender[Calendar.MINUTE] =  asarTime.getInt("asarTimeMinutes",0)
                    calender[Calendar.SECOND] = 0
                    calender[Calendar.MILLISECOND] = 0
                


                asrTxt.text = ("" + asarTime.getInt("asarTimeHour", 0) + ":"
                        + asarTime.getInt("asarTimeMinutes",0) + " PM")

                alarmAsr()

            }else{
                editor.putBoolean("asarTimesSwitch",false)
                editor.putBoolean("asarTXT", false)
                editor.apply()
                asrSwitch.isChecked = false

                asrTxt.text = " "
            }
        }
 fun alarmAsr(){
        alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val i = Intent(this, asarBroadcastReceiver::class.java)

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 4, i,0)



        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.timeInMillis,
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent
        )
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `calendar[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY]=20`?

Comment: @kilian no i didn't